# WS Endpoint Address on a Glassfish server

Tags: web-services, annotations, glassfish, uri, java-metro-framework

Is there any way to specify an ws endpoint address on glassfish server using annotations only?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? For a service? client code? Can you illustrate what you want to do with an example?

Comment: org.jboss.ws.annotation.WebContext
In JBoss you can specify it using this annotation, contextRoot and urlpattern attributes. in Glassfish you have to use xml descriptors

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Web Services Metadata Annotations (JSR 181)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ws.jaxws.emitter.doc/topics/cwsandoc001.html).

The @WebService annotation has a parameter:

**wsdlLocation**

> Specifies the Web address of the WSDL
>   document that defines the Web service.
>   The Web address is either relative or
>   absolute. (String)

Comment: No, it specifies location for existing WSDL file, not a potential endpoint address

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'serviceName' attribute on the @WebService annotation what you are after?

From http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/annotations.html#2.1%20javax.jws.WebService|outline:

**serviceName** - The Service name of the web service: wsdl:service 
Default: The unqualified name of the Java class or interface + “Service”

Any context path before that would be controlled by the location to which you deploy the web application containing the application, as would the domain name i.e for a service class 'DoSomething' deployed in a web application called 'myappcontext' in a host container of 'my.webservice.com'.

```
https://my.webservice.com/myappcontext/DoSomethingService
```